# Comments offset

Tags: comments, sort, offsets

I need to display comments starting from the second, omitting the first. 
With posts I did it using "offset" but I can't find anything similar for comments.
Since I'm using threaded comments, must start from the second comment that is not a child (only parent comments).
I'm using wp_list_comments with a callback.

EDIT2: this is actual comments.php code, after replies:

```
      <?php 
$i = 2;
if ( have_comments() ) : 
if ( $i > 1 ) :
?>
    <div id="comments">
    <h3 id="comments-title" class="color-<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?>">
</h3>


    <?php 

     global $wp_query; 
     $comments_arr = $wp_query->comments; 
     $comments_arr = sort( $comments_arr); 
     $comments_arr = array_pop( $comments_arr );
     $comments_arr = usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');                 
     wp_list_comments('callback=gtcn_basic_callback', $comments_arr); 

    ?>


    <?php
    $i++; // count up
    endif; // If $i > 1
    else : if ( ! comments_open() ) : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' ); ?></p>

    <?php 
      endif; // end ! comments_open() 
endif; // end have_comments()  ?>
</div>
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

Result: comments are not anymore ordered by karma (comment_comparator function) and the first comment (comment with top karma that I want to hide) is still displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
global $wp_query, $post; 
$comments_arr = $wp_query->comments; 
$comments_arr = sort( $comments_arr); 
$comments_arr = array_pop( $comments_arr );
$comments_arr = usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');

$comment_count = get_comment_count($post->ID);

 ?>
<h3 id="comments-title"><?php
    printf(
    _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number(), 'YOUR_THEMES_TEXTDOMAIN' ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
    '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' 
);
?></h3>
if ( have_comments() ) : 
?><ul class="commentlist"><?php
for ( $i = 0; $i < $comment_count; $i++ )
{
    // do stuff: 
        // This shows you everything you got inside the comments array
        // Call it like this: echo $comments_arr[$i]['comment_author'];
        var_dump( $comments_arr[$i] ); 
    // end do stuff
} // endforeach;
?></ul><?php

elseif ('open' == $post->comment_status) :
    // If there are no comments, but status = open
    ?><p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'No Comments.', 'YOUR_THEMES_TEXTDOMAIN' ); ?></p><?php
endif; // If $i > 1

else : // or, if comments are not allowed:
    if ( ! comments_open() ) : 
    ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'YOUR_THEMES_TEXTDOMAIN' ); ?></p>
    <?php 
    endif; // end ! comments_open() 
endif; // end have_comments() 
?>
```

Ad your current loop:

No need for `$counter = 2;` (called nowhere).

If you already got your `$comments_arr`, why not simply:

```
$comments_arr = sort( $comments_arr); 
$comments_arr = array_pop( $comments_arr ); 
$comments_arr = usort( $comments_arr );
```

OR

```
$comments_arr = unset( $comments_arr[0] ); 
$comments_arr = usort( $comments_arr );
```

Comment: Thanks kaiser, but it's not working for me. It broke the layout and comments are not displayed anymore. I added my actual comments.php code to the question.

Comment: It should. There's close to no difference to your code and it's taken from twenty ten. I guess you have forgotten to close some html tag before the comments loop. See edit.

Comment: but `if ( $i > 1 ) :` should not be inside a php tag?

Comment: You're right. That was my fault. Most was copy/paste. Just try again after the edit and try to find and resolve errors that depend on `<?php ?>` as you did before :)

Comment: This is making me nuts. It looks simple, I understand it but, when I correctly put the code, the comments are not displayed anymore, only the comment form. If I comment `if ( $i > 1 ) :` and `endif; // If $i > 1` everything starts to work again.

Comment: Stick with the last lines i wrote in my Q.

Comment: Hi, I'm back after a travel. Still trying all the options, but is not working. Maybe with a callback function i need to put the code inside the callback, rather than the comments.php. Also, tried with your $comments_arr part but it is messing up my comments (they are sorted by karma, that's the function comment_comparator I'm calling). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: "messing up" & "not working" won't help anything with solving the issue. You need to be as specific as possible with your descriptions.

Comment: Kaiser, you're totally right. That happened because I am a designer rather than a coder and not a native english speaker. I am trying now to recreate the errors and will explain them better. Thanks again for your help and advice.

Comment: Updated the question with the new code and the resulting output.

Comment: Updated the Answer. Be cure that you read every line carefully. First: you forgot to wrap the input arguments for `wp_list_comments` in an `array( 'callback' => 'whatever' )` and Second: You can't simply add the array to the function - the function can't take any input as it will query the comments herself. You need to build your callback right into the `//do stuff` call inside the loop in the A, because you can't save the output of `wp_list_comments` and there's no alternative.